# Issue passing function return to extend object

Tags: javascript, object

Remember, before killing the messenger... I´m learning.

I´m trying to "use" the return of a function on file B to extend an Object on file A. At future I would have several function extending, depending the case the object.

So, here´s the case.

File A (A.html)

```
<script src="B.js"></script>

<script>

var _USER = _USER || {};
_USER.levelOne = { 
  "Name" : "Jon",
  "LastName" : "Doe",
  "Age" : 30
};

_USER.levelOne.something = "some";

</script>
```

File B (B.js)

```
function userNickName(nickname) {
  var info = {
    "NickName" : nickname
    };
  return info;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var userNick = $("#inputx").text();
  userNickName(userNick);
});
```

So, the object of File B should be used on File A.

I tried the following on file A

```
var nickFunction = userNickName;
jQuery.extend(_USER.levelOne, nickFunction);
```

I searched a good time but I couldn´t find a solution or useful help. I was thinking, as well, since I will have several function on file B, to create another function inside all functions passing the object as parameter.

As I said before, this is not a real scenario. Just I doing some practice and trying to understand.

Any help, recommendation and other point of view will be of help. Thanks

Comment: Theres no reason to split it up on two files, why would one do so?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because I´m trying to keep functions on other file as part of the learning. Again, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some peculiar things here:

In B.js you're calling:

```
userNickName(userNick);
```

but your not actually doing anything with the return value. `userNickName` returns the object you want, so it's not clear why you are calling the function here.

In A.html, you are saving the function to a new variable and then passing that to `Object.extend`:

```
var nickFunction = userNickName;
// nickFunction is now a function, not the result of the function
jQuery.extend(_USER.levelOne, nickFunction);
```

It looks like you want to grab the value of an input and add that value to nickname. So you need to decide which part of the app is responsible for getting the value from the input. I think it should be the A.html not the B.js because should be reusable on different html pages. In that case, A.html needs something like:

```
// the value to pass to the subject 
var userNick = $("#inputx").val(); // note val() not text()

// call the function from B.js and pass it the value
// it will return an object which will then be added to _USER
jQuery.extend(_USER.levelOne, userNickName(userNick));
```

The above should probably go inside `$(document).ready()` in A.html.

Here's a snippet with it all together:

```js
// this is in B.js
function userNickName(nickname) {
  var info = {
    "NickName": nickname
  };
  return info;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="B.js"></script> -->
<script>
  var _USER = _USER || {};
  _USER.levelOne = {
    "Name": "Jon",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Age": 30
  };

  _USER.levelOne.something = "some";

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var userNick = $("#inputx").val();
    jQuery.extend(_USER.levelOne, userNickName(userNick));
    console.log(_USER)
  })
</script>

<body>
  <input id="inputx" type="text" value="Mark"></input>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark_M for your answer and excuse my small, tiny knowledge on the matter. So, if I want to have the functions on another file and the code to pass a parameter to that function, parameter that would be the value for the property of the object for then, on file A, which includes file B extend the object with the return of the function, is not possible to do it? I´m trying to understand.

Comment: Thanks, Mark_M I was writing when you were updating the post with the snippet. I truly appreciate it. So, there´s no way to have the var userNick... on file B, pass the value to A and then on A extend the object: jQuery.extend(_USER.levelOne, userNickName(userNick)); Right...?

Comment: Sorry, Peter, I'm not quite sure I understand this question. In general, you can do almost anything you want.  You can have B.js get the input value itself, but it means it's bound tightly to the particular html so it's not re-useable. Now that it's all calling the right stuff, there's no technical reason things can't be moved around. It should still work. Also, which ever part is responsible for getting the input value needs to be in the document.ready() so it doesn't try and lookup the value before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark. You understood it right. I was confused but you pushed me to my original path and the right one. Thanks a lot.